# Use toggleClass() instead of addClass()/removeClass() in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good evening! I implement accordion functionality with addClass()/removeClass() method. There are:
1. HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="functionality">Accordion</div>
    <ul class="accordion-wrapper">
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

2.CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.accordion-wrapper .title {
    border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-wrapper .text {
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.accordion-wrapper .active {
    display: block;
}

.functionality {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 12px 8px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

3.JS

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        function accordion() {
            var $clicked = $('.title');
            var $text = $('.text');

            $clicked.click(function() {
                var $instance = $(this);
                var $currentText = $instance.closest('li').find('.text');
                if ($currentText.hasClass('active')) {
                    $currentText.removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $text.removeClass('active');
                    $currentText.addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
        accordion();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

But I think that I can transformed it with using toggleClass() instead og addClass() and removeClass(). Can you help me? But don't create new accordion - only transform existing
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is replace your `if.. else` block with `.toggleClass()` like Make sure you also use `$text.removeClass('active');` so that you remove any `active` class on the `.text` elements.

More explanation in the code comment below.

```js
/* I've refactored your JS */

(function accordion($) {
  //not caching variables as they are used only once

  $('.title').on('click', function() {
    //no need of closest and find, simple .next() is enough here
    var $currentText = $(this).next();
    
     //replace your if.. else with the below lines
                
     /* add this to remove all active classes which you 
        appended previously, you don't need this if you are 
        fine keeping multiple dropdown in active state */
       $('.text').not($currentText).removeClass('active');

      /* Here, we toggle the active class */
      $currentText.toggleClass('active');
  });
})(jQuery); //passing jQuery to iife function
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.accordion-wrapper .title {
    border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-wrapper .text {
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.accordion-wrapper .active {
    display: block;
}

.functionality {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 12px 8px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="functionality">Accordion</div>
    <ul class="accordion-wrapper">
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not work as I need. For example. I open description by click on title reply to this description. But when I click again on this title the description doesn't hide. I need to implement it. Have some idea?

Comment: @AntinJu aah, minor issue, will fix it

Comment: Oh, thank you! Thats great! Do you think it can be imlemented with another way?

Comment: @AntinJu Yes, I can refactor your code to a great extent

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by just toggling `.active` on the `.title`, then use the CSS sibling selector to toggle the display of `.text`

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    function accordion() {
      var $clicked = $(".title");
      var $text = $(".text");

      $clicked.click(function() {
        $clicked.not($(this)).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
    }
    accordion();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.accordion-wrapper .title {
    border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-wrapper .text {
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.active + .text {
    display: block;
}

.functionality {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 12px 8px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="functionality">Accordion</div>
    <ul class="accordion-wrapper">
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="text">Description</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Another issue. It doesn't hide description when I click by another title

Comment: @AntinJu ah sorry I missed that part. Updated.